# How to sum same number in a csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, log-analysis

I have a csv file and there are Date, count, and service column. There are many date,count and service columns but this is the example I will write below.

```
Number  Count   Service       Number    Count   service
0        13   NO SERVICE        0        10 
1        14   tcpmux            1        10 
2         9   compressnet       2        14
```

So I want the answer like :

```
Number   Total Count    Service
0            23         NO SERVICE
1            24         tcpmux
2            23         compressnet
```

How do I do the code in pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.read_csv ("/Users/mani/Desktop/monthly report/geoip/2017-20dstipsum12.csv")
hasil =  df.groupby(['NUMBER']).sum()
hasil.to_csv('gotttt.txt', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: There are duplicate columns names?

Comment: @jezrael yes there are lot like that with same column name but these are 2 examples

Comment: What is your pandas version? Because `read_csv` in newer version of pandas add `.1`, `.2` to duplicate columns names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If columns `Number` are same in all data:

```
#sum all column Count
df['Total Count'] = df['Count'].sum(axis=1)
#select first and third column and join Total Count column
df = df.iloc[:, [0,2]].join(df['Total Count'])
print (df)
   Number  Total Count   Total Service
0       0           23      NO SERVICE
1       1           24          tcpmux  
2       2           23     compressnet
```

---

In newer version of pandas are deduplicated columns names in `read_csv`, so need [`filter`](http://panda.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for select columns:

```
print (df)
   Number  Count      Service  Number.1  Count.1 Service.1
0       0     13   NO SERVICE         0       10          
1       1     14       tcpmux         1       10          
2       2      9  compressnet         2       14 

df['Total Count'] = df.filter(like='Count').sum(axis=1)

df = df[['Number','Total Count','Service']]
print (df)
   Number  Total Count   Total Service
0       0           23      NO SERVICE  
1       1           24          tcpmux 
2       2           23     compressnet
```

Comment: I got this error  
No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: I guess there are no duplicates columns names, so need second solution. What return `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to panda so I do not understand (df.clomns.tolist())

Comment: OK, can you send me to my emal in my profile your file (if not confidental) with desired output for first 5 rows?

Comment: I have sent email to you. Please check